# How to give autofocus to a element when another element has it?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to give a `textarea` (which is added when you click on a button) autofocus with the `autofocus` attribute, but when I do that it doesn't works and I get this message on the console:

```
Autofocus processing was blocked because a document already has a focused element.
```

So now the question is:
**How can I get the focus to the textarea when some other element already has it?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Giving autofocus to a textarea is basically saying "When the page loads, this textarea should be focused"
So focusing another element isn't a problem:
If that error is occurring, just use the `.blur()` method on the textarea you want to lose focus on. Then do the `.focus()` method on the one you want focused

```js
function focus1() {
  document.getElementById('ele1').focus()
}

function focus2() {
  document.getElementById('ele2').focus()
}
```

```html
<textarea id="ele1"></textarea>
<textarea id="ele2"></textarea>

<button onclick="focus1()">Click to focus inp1</button>
<button onclick="focus2()">Click to focus inp2</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

After adding the `textarea` control then set focus to that control.
I thing this will solve your problem.
On button click call `addTextArea()` function.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    var cntctrl = 0;
    function addTextArea() {
        try {
            var s = document.createElement('textarea');
            cntctrl = cntctrl + 1;
            var id = 'txtarea' + cntctrl;
            s.setAttribute('id', id);
            s.setAttribute('class', "txtareaclass");
            s.setAttribute('rows', "4");
            s.setAttribute('cols', "100");
            document.body.appendChild(s);
            document.getElementById(id).focus();
       } 
       catch (e) {
           console.log('Adding Textarea failed!.');
           console.log('Error: ' + e);
       }
       return false;
    }      
    </script>
```